# Debezium PostgreSQL connector not creating topic

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, debezium

A Kafka topic is not created when I use start the Debezium connector for PostgreSQL. Here's what I have in my properties file:

```
name=testdb
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector
topic.prefix=test
database.hostname=localhost
database.port=5432
database.user=postgres
database.password=root
database.dbname=testdb
database.server.name=testdb
table.include.list=ipaddrs
plugin.name=pgoutput
```

According to [this](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/postgresql.html#postgresql-topic-names), the topic should be named `testdb.myschema.ipaddrs` (`myschema` is the name of my schema). However `bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server 192.168.56.1:9092` returns nothing. A topic is not created if I add a row to table `ipaddrs`.

Kakfka connect starts up successfully when I run `bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/postgres.properties` without any exceptions.

I have `auto.create.topics.enable = true`. `http://localhost:8083/connectors/testdb/status` shows this:

`{"name":"testdb","connector":{"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"10.0.0.48:8083"},"tasks":[{"id":0,"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"10.0.0.48:8083"}],"type":"source"}`

I am not running Zookeeper. I am running Kafka with KRaft.

Comment: 1) Did you disable auto topic creation on Kafka? 2) If you run `curl http://localhost:8083/connectors/testdb/status`, are any tasks running?

Answer (score 1):

`table.include.list` was not correct. It has to include the schema. So it should have been `myschema.ipaddrs` in my example. In addition, it seems like the documentation is incorrect for the [topic name](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/postgresql.html#postgresql-topic-names). In my system it is `<topic.prefix>.<table name>`. So in my example, it's `test.myschema.ipaddrs`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the database has the correct configuration to work with the [Debezium postgreSQL](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/postgresql.html#postgresql-overview)  connector, you can remove "database.dbname" if *ipaddrs* is table name not repeated in another schema.

Comment: If I remove that, the connector does not start because of this error: `The 'database.dbname' value is invalid: A value is required`

Comment: I'm using debezium with mysql, in the connector I have database.include.list. I don't use database.dbname