# Topic not created when using debezium/connect Docker image

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, debezium

A Kafka topic for my table is not created when using the [debezium/connect](https://hub.docker.com/r/debezium/connect) Docker image. Here's how I'm starting the container:

```
docker run -it --rm --name debezium -p 8083:8083 -e GROUP_ID=1 -e CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my-connect-configs \
-e OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my-connect-offsets  -e BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=192.168.56.1:9092 \
-e CONNECT_NAME=my-connector -e CONNECT_CONNECTOR_CLASS=io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector \
-e CONNECT_TOPIC_PREFIX=my-prefix -e CONNECT_DATABASE_HOSTNAME=host.docker.internal -e CONNECT_DATABASE_PORT=5432 \
-e CONNECT_DATABASE_USER=postgres -e CONNECT_DATABASE_PASSWORD=root -e DATABASE_SERVER_NAME=mydb \
-e CONNECT_DATABASE_DBNAME=mydb -e CONNECT_TABLE_INCLUDE_LIST=myschema.my_table -e CONNECT_PLUGIN_NAME=pgoutput \
debezium/connect
```

I've tried using `CONNECT__` instead of `CONNECT_`, but I get the same results. A topic for the table is not created if I use the API:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 127.0.0.1:8083/connectors --data '
{
  "name": "prism",  
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector", 
    "topic.prefix": my-connector",
    "database.hostname": "host.docker.internal", 
    "database.port": "5432", 
    "database.user": "postgres", 
    "database.password": "root", 
    "database.server.name": "mydb", 
    "database.dbname" : "mydb", 
    "table.include.list": "myschema.my_table",
    "plugin.name": "pgoutput"
  }
}'
```

The topics `my-connect-configs` and `my-connect-offsets`, specified by `CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC` and `OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC`, are created.

`http://localhost:8083/connectors/my-connector/status` shows this:

```
{"name":"my-connector","connector":{"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"172.17.0.3:8083"},"tasks":[{"id":0,"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"172.17.0.3:8083"}],"type":"source"}
```

I was able to create a topic when using `bin/connect-standalone.sh` instead of the Docker image as per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74103659/debezium-postgresql-connector-not-creating-topic).

Automatic topic creation is enabled and I don't see any errors/warnings in the log.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check kafka connect container logs, what msg it shows when it tries to insert the data to kafka cluster.
2. You need to enable auto topic creation in kafka broker config, checkout [this doc](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/configuration/topic-auto-create-config.html)
3. Make sure that table exist in the db and `"table.include.list": "myschema.my_table",` is correct. For experimentation you can remove this config temporary.

You can use UI platform created by redpanda team to manage topic, broker and kafka-connect config - [here](https://github.com/redpanda-data/console)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the underlying table didn't have any data, and, therefore, the topic was not created. The topic is created either if the table has data when the connector is started or if rows are added while the connector is running.